# Cache manifest chrome reload behavior

Tags: html, wordpress, caching, manifest

I'm using a dynamic cache manifest and when I reload the browser after the initial load, the browser doesn't pull certain assets.

Here's the generated cache:

```
CACHE MANIFEST
# version: 87175d3b8e20b642cd18319d55883e4e

CACHE:
http://www.neverwithout.net/crocker-wp/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/windwardpointe-logo1.png
../../themes/twentythirteen/rtl.css
../../themes/twentythirteen/screenshot.png
../../themes/twentythirteen/style.css
../../themes/twentythirteen/css/editor-style.css
../../themes/twentythirteen/css/ie.css
../../themes/twentythirteen/css/webfont/climacons-font.css
../../themes/twentythirteen/css/webfont/climacons-webfont.eot
../../themes/twentythirteen/css/webfont/climacons-webfont.svg
../../themes/twentythirteen/css/webfont/climacons-webfont.ttf
../../themes/twentythirteen/css/webfont/climacons-webfont.woff
../../themes/twentythirteen/css/webfont/Climacons.ttf
../../themes/twentythirteen/fonts/COPYING.txt
../../themes/twentythirteen/fonts/genericons-regular-webfont.eot
../../themes/twentythirteen/fonts/genericons-regular-webfont.svg
../../themes/twentythirteen/fonts/genericons-regular-webfont.ttf
../../themes/twentythirteen/fonts/genericons-regular-webfont.woff
../../themes/twentythirteen/fonts/genericons.css
../../themes/twentythirteen/fonts/LICENSE.txt
../../themes/twentythirteen/fonts/OpenSans-Bold-webfont.eot
../../themes/twentythirteen/fonts/OpenSans-Bold-webfont.svg
../../themes/twentythirteen/fonts/OpenSans-Bold-webfont.ttf
../../themes/twentythirteen/fonts/OpenSans-Bold-webfont.woff
../../themes/twentythirteen/fonts/OpenSans-BoldItalic-webfont.svg
../../themes/twentythirteen/fonts/OpenSans-BoldItalic-webfont.eot
../../themes/twentythirteen/fonts/OpenSans-BoldItalic-webfont.ttf
../../themes/twentythirteen/fonts/OpenSans-BoldItalic-webfont.woff
../../themes/twentythirteen/fonts/OpenSans-ExtraBold-webfont.eot
../../themes/twentythirteen/fonts/OpenSans-ExtraBold-webfont.svg
../../themes/twentythirteen/fonts/OpenSans-ExtraBold-webfont.ttf
../../themes/twentythirteen/fonts/OpenSans-ExtraBold-webfont.woff
../../themes/twentythirteen/fonts/OpenSans-ExtraBoldItalic-webfont.eot
../../themes/twentythirteen/fonts/OpenSans-ExtraBoldItalic-webfont.ttf
../../themes/twentythirteen/fonts/OpenSans-ExtraBoldItalic-webfont.svg
../../themes/twentythirteen/fonts/OpenSans-ExtraBoldItalic-webfont.woff
../../themes/twentythirteen/fonts/OpenSans-Italic-webfont.eot
../../themes/twentythirteen/fonts/OpenSans-Italic-webfont.svg
../../themes/twentythirteen/fonts/OpenSans-Italic-webfont.ttf
../../themes/twentythirteen/fonts/OpenSans-Light-webfont.eot
../../themes/twentythirteen/fonts/OpenSans-Italic-webfont.woff
../../themes/twentythirteen/fonts/OpenSans-Light-webfont.ttf
../../themes/twentythirteen/fonts/OpenSans-Light-webfont.svg
../../themes/twentythirteen/fonts/OpenSans-Light-webfont.woff
../../themes/twentythirteen/fonts/OpenSans-LightItalic-webfont.eot
../../themes/twentythirteen/fonts/OpenSans-LightItalic-webfont.svg
../../themes/twentythirteen/fonts/OpenSans-LightItalic-webfont.ttf
../../themes/twentythirteen/fonts/OpenSans-LightItalic-webfont.woff
../../themes/twentythirteen/fonts/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.eot
../../themes/twentythirteen/fonts/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.svg
../../themes/twentythirteen/fonts/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.ttf
../../themes/twentythirteen/fonts/OpenSans-Semibold-webfont.eot
../../themes/twentythirteen/fonts/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.woff
../../themes/twentythirteen/fonts/OpenSans-Semibold-webfont.svg
../../themes/twentythirteen/fonts/OpenSans-Semibold-webfont.ttf
../../themes/twentythirteen/fonts/OpenSans-Semibold-webfont.woff
../../themes/twentythirteen/fonts/OpenSans-SemiboldItalic-webfont.eot
../../themes/twentythirteen/fonts/OpenSans-SemiboldItalic-webfont.svg
../../themes/twentythirteen/fonts/OpenSans-SemiboldItalic-webfont.ttf
../../themes/twentythirteen/fonts/OpenSans-SemiboldItalic-webfont.woff
../../themes/twentythirteen/fonts/opensans_bold_macroman/OpenSans-Bold-demo.html
../../themes/twentythirteen/fonts/opensans_bold_macroman/stylesheet.css
../../themes/twentythirteen/fonts/opensans_bold_macroman/specimen_files/easytabs.js
../../themes/twentythirteen/fonts/opensans_bold_macroman/specimen_files/grid_12-825-55-15.css
../../themes/twentythirteen/fonts/opensans_bold_macroman/specimen_files/OpenSans-Bold-cleartype.png
../../themes/twentythirteen/fonts/opensans_bold_macroman/specimen_files/specimen_stylesheet.css
../../themes/twentythirteen/fonts/opensans_bolditalic_macroman/OpenSans-BoldItalic-demo.html
../../themes/twentythirteen/fonts/opensans_bolditalic_macroman/stylesheet.css
../../themes/twentythirteen/fonts/opensans_bolditalic_macroman/specimen_files/grid_12-825-55-15.css
../../themes/twentythirteen/fonts/opensans_bolditalic_macroman/specimen_files/easytabs.js
../../themes/twentythirteen/fonts/opensans_bolditalic_macroman/specimen_files/specimen_stylesheet.css
../../themes/twentythirteen/fonts/opensans_bolditalic_macroman/specimen_files/OpenSans-BoldItalic-cleartype.png
../../themes/twentythirteen/fonts/opensans_extrabold_macroman/OpenSans-ExtraBold-demo.html
../../themes/twentythirteen/fonts/opensans_extrabold_macroman/stylesheet.css
../../themes/twentythirteen/fonts/opensans_extrabold_macroman/specimen_files/easytabs.js
../../themes/twentythirteen/fonts/opensans_extrabold_macroman/specimen_files/grid_12-825-55-15.css
../../themes/twentythirteen/fonts/opensans_extrabold_macroman/specimen_files/OpenSans-ExtraBold-cleartype.png
../../themes/twentythirteen/fonts/opensans_extrabold_macroman/specimen_files/specimen_stylesheet.css
../../themes/twentythirteen/fonts/opensans_extrabolditalic_macroman/OpenSans-ExtraBoldItalic-demo.html
../../themes/twentythirteen/fonts/opensans_extrabolditalic_macroman/stylesheet.css
../../themes/twentythirteen/fonts/opensans_extrabolditalic_macroman/specimen_files/grid_12-825-55-15.css
../../themes/twentythirteen/fonts/opensans_extrabolditalic_macroman/specimen_files/easytabs.js
../../themes/twentythirteen/fonts/opensans_extrabolditalic_macroman/specimen_files/specimen_stylesheet.css
../../themes/twentythirteen/fonts/opensans_extrabolditalic_macroman/specimen_files/OpenSans-ExtraBoldItalic-cleartype.png
../../themes/twentythirteen/fonts/opensans_italic_macroman/OpenSans-Italic-demo.html
../../themes/twentythirteen/fonts/opensans_italic_macroman/stylesheet.css
../../themes/twentythirteen/fonts/opensans_italic_macroman/specimen_files/easytabs.js
../../themes/twentythirteen/fonts/opensans_italic_macroman/specimen_files/grid_12-825-55-15.css
../../themes/twentythirteen/fonts/opensans_italic_macroman/specimen_files/OpenSans-Italic-cleartype.png
../../themes/twentythirteen/fonts/opensans_italic_macroman/specimen_files/specimen_stylesheet.css
../../themes/twentythirteen/fonts/opensans_light_macroman/OpenSans-Light-demo.html
../../themes/twentythirteen/fonts/opensans_light_macroman/stylesheet.css
../../themes/twentythirteen/fonts/opensans_light_macroman/specimen_files/grid_12-825-55-15.css
../../themes/twentythirteen/fonts/opensans_light_macroman/specimen_files/easytabs.js
../../themes/twentythirteen/fonts/opensans_light_macroman/specimen_files/specimen_stylesheet.css
../../themes/twentythirteen/fonts/opensans_light_macroman/specimen_files/OpenSans-Light-cleartype.png
../../themes/twentythirteen/fonts/opensans_lightitalic_macroman/OpenSans-LightItalic-demo.html
../../themes/twentythirteen/fonts/opensans_lightitalic_macroman/stylesheet.css
../../themes/twentythirteen/fonts/opensans_lightitalic_macroman/specimen_files/easytabs.js
../../themes/twentythirteen/fonts/opensans_lightitalic_macroman/specimen_files/grid_12-825-55-15.css
../../themes/twentythirteen/fonts/opensans_lightitalic_macroman/specimen_files/OpenSans-LightItalic-cleartype.png
../../themes/twentythirteen/fonts/opensans_lightitalic_macroman/specimen_files/specimen_stylesheet.css
../../themes/twentythirteen/fonts/opensans_regular_macroman/OpenSans-Regular-demo.html
../../themes/twentythirteen/fonts/opensans_regular_macroman/stylesheet.css
../../themes/twentythirteen/fonts/opensans_regular_macroman/specimen_files/grid_12-825-55-15.css
../../themes/twentythirteen/fonts/opensans_regular_macroman/specimen_files/easytabs.js
../../themes/twentythirteen/fonts/opensans_regular_macroman/specimen_files/specimen_stylesheet.css
../../themes/twentythirteen/fonts/opensans_regular_macroman/specimen_files/OpenSans-Regular-cleartype.png
../../themes/twentythirteen/fonts/opensans_semibold_macroman/OpenSans-Semibold-demo.html
../../themes/twentythirteen/fonts/opensans_semibold_macroman/stylesheet.css
../../themes/twentythirteen/fonts/opensans_semibold_macroman/specimen_files/easytabs.js
../../themes/twentythirteen/fonts/opensans_semibold_macroman/specimen_files/grid_12-825-55-15.css
../../themes/twentythirteen/fonts/opensans_semibold_macroman/specimen_files/OpenSans-Semibold-cleartype.png
../../themes/twentythirteen/fonts/opensans_semibold_macroman/specimen_files/specimen_stylesheet.css
../../themes/twentythirteen/fonts/opensans_semibolditalic_macroman/OpenSans-SemiboldItalic-demo.html
../../themes/twentythirteen/fonts/opensans_semibolditalic_macroman/stylesheet.css
../../themes/twentythirteen/fonts/opensans_semibolditalic_macroman/specimen_files/grid_12-825-55-15.css
../../themes/twentythirteen/fonts/opensans_semibolditalic_macroman/specimen_files/easytabs.js
../../themes/twentythirteen/fonts/opensans_semibolditalic_macroman/specimen_files/specimen_stylesheet.css
../../themes/twentythirteen/fonts/opensans_semibolditalic_macroman/specimen_files/OpenSans-SemiboldItalic-cleartype.png
../../themes/twentythirteen/images/crocker-stream.png
../../themes/twentythirteen/images/dotted-line-2x.png
../../themes/twentythirteen/images/dotted-line-light-2x.png
../../themes/twentythirteen/images/dotted-line-light.png
../../themes/twentythirteen/images/search-icon-2x.png
../../themes/twentythirteen/images/dotted-line.png
../../themes/twentythirteen/images/search-icon.png
../../themes/twentythirteen/images/headers/circle-thumbnail.png
../../themes/twentythirteen/images/headers/circle.png
../../themes/twentythirteen/images/headers/diamond-thumbnail.png
../../themes/twentythirteen/images/headers/diamond.png
../../themes/twentythirteen/images/headers/star-thumbnail.png
../../themes/twentythirteen/images/headers/star.png
../../themes/twentythirteen/images/weather/0.svg
../../themes/twentythirteen/images/weather/1.svg
../../themes/twentythirteen/images/weather/10.svg
../../themes/twentythirteen/images/weather/11.svg
../../themes/twentythirteen/images/weather/12.svg
../../themes/twentythirteen/images/weather/13.svg
../../themes/twentythirteen/images/weather/14.svg
../../themes/twentythirteen/images/weather/15.svg
../../themes/twentythirteen/images/weather/16.svg
../../themes/twentythirteen/images/weather/17.svg
../../themes/twentythirteen/images/weather/18.svg
../../themes/twentythirteen/images/weather/2.svg
../../themes/twentythirteen/images/weather/20.svg
../../themes/twentythirteen/images/weather/21.svg
../../themes/twentythirteen/images/weather/22.svg
../../themes/twentythirteen/images/weather/23.svg
../../themes/twentythirteen/images/weather/24.svg
../../themes/twentythirteen/images/weather/25.svg
../../themes/twentythirteen/images/weather/26.svg
../../themes/twentythirteen/images/weather/27.svg
../../themes/twentythirteen/images/weather/28.svg
../../themes/twentythirteen/images/weather/29.svg
../../themes/twentythirteen/images/weather/3.svg
../../themes/twentythirteen/images/weather/30.svg
../../themes/twentythirteen/images/weather/31.svg
../../themes/twentythirteen/images/weather/32.svg
../../themes/twentythirteen/images/weather/33.svg
../../themes/twentythirteen/images/weather/34.svg
../../themes/twentythirteen/images/weather/35.svg
../../themes/twentythirteen/images/weather/36.svg
../../themes/twentythirteen/images/weather/37.svg
../../themes/twentythirteen/images/weather/38.svg
../../themes/twentythirteen/images/weather/39.svg
../../themes/twentythirteen/images/weather/4.svg
../../themes/twentythirteen/images/weather/40.svg
../../themes/twentythirteen/images/weather/41.svg
../../themes/twentythirteen/images/weather/42.svg
../../themes/twentythirteen/images/weather/43.svg
../../themes/twentythirteen/images/weather/44.svg
../../themes/twentythirteen/images/weather/45.svg
../../themes/twentythirteen/images/weather/46.svg
../../themes/twentythirteen/images/weather/47.svg
../../themes/twentythirteen/images/weather/5.svg
../../themes/twentythirteen/images/weather/6.svg
../../themes/twentythirteen/images/weather/7.svg
../../themes/twentythirteen/images/weather/9.svg
../../themes/twentythirteen/js/functions.js
../../themes/twentythirteen/js/html5.js
../../themes/twentythirteen/js/jquery.columnizer.js
../../themes/twentythirteen/js/jquery.nwrapper.js
../../themes/twentythirteen/js/moment.min.js
../../themes/twentythirteen/js/mustache.js
../../themes/twentythirteen/js/theme-customizer.js
../../themes/twentythirteen/js/whatweather-1.2.min.js
../../themes/twentythirteen/languages/twentythirteen.pot
```

After the cache checking event it fails to load these resources when I reload the browser:
[image]

I disabled google fonts so it wouldn't fail on that but it still failed on the others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I figured out why it's not working. Some of the libraries don't have cache expiration values. So, notice all the files that fail have ?ver=##. I removed all the version numbers that are referenced and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

### Provide the below lines (Network Section) after cache section

NETWORK:

```
    NETWORK:
    *
    http://*
    https://*
```